# CAF Receiver: How to change the volume / mute?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

How to change the volume / mute the stream audio without using the controls on the cast extension ? I have implemented a slider on the sender side . This passes the volume value to receiver . But I do not understand , how to set volume or mute/ unmute command is send from the receiver app to the player.
What APIs should I use for this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you been able to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find/reverse-engineer it. I haven't found this in the documentation though.

```
cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance().setSystemVolumeLevel(0.5) // 50%
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the volume directly of the HTML media element.

If you have a custom player, you should be able to set the player volume: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.media.Player#setVolume

Comment: It works fine with the V2 Receivers but not with CAF Receivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 var playerContext = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();
 var playerManager = this.playerContext.getPlayerManager();
 var volumeRequest = new cast.framework.messages.VolumeRequestData();
 volumeRequest.volume.level = level; // 0 - 1
 playerManager.sendLocalMediaRequest(volumeRequest);`
```

But the volume bar doesn't show. I don't know why.